# How to configure/override Maven property used as parent version in dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Suppose there are two 3rd-party Maven artifacts with the following POM.XMLs:

artifact1 POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group1</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
<version>${artifact1.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <artifact1.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</artifact1.version>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>../artifact2</module>
</modules>
```

artifact2 POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>${artifact1.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../artifact1</relativePath>
</parent>
```

They are built normally using

```
mvn clean install
```

Now, if I try to reuse artifact2 in a 3rd POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group2</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group1</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After executing...

```
mvn clean install
```

...the build fails trying to locate group1:artifact1:pom:${artifact1.version}

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project artifact3: Could not resolve dependencies for project group2:artifact3:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at group1:artifact2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for group1:artifact2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact group1:artifact1:pom:${artifact1.version} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

And setting the property in the command-line doesn't work either:

```
mvn clean install -Dartifact1.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

How can I use artifact2 as a dependency?

Comment: _They are built normally using ..._ Really? Hard to believe. On which version of Maven did you try this?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

`<parent>` doesn't allow variables. Because in order to get a list of variables Maven first has to build Effective POM and for this it needs to resolve parents.

Even if there is some version of Maven that allowed such module to be installed it's not a working solution in general. Maven's ideology is that all the dependencies (including parent) could be downloaded from a repo and are not necessarily present on local FS/in the reactor. With properties in the parent dependency definition you violate this rule.

Comment: You can use variables in dependencies versions and they works fine. When variables are loaded after the dependencies you have an issue, which can usually be worked around using system properties. Except that this workaround doesn't work with the <parent> tag.

Comment: Still, Maven accepts the setup of the first 2 artifacts. They are built successfully to the very end and can be distributed. I am trying to find a workaround to reuse them, preferably without having to hack/fork the first 2 artifacts. Hacks inside the 3rd POM.XML are ok.